# Replace text in dataframe column if it appears in subsequent columns

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a list with thousands of rows and am trying to learn vectorised methods to speed up processing. I am wondering if the following is possible.

In the following table I want to remove the text in the "TextToRemove" column from the text in the "Full Name" column. So for row 0 the expected output should be "Active Auto MY16"

I have tried `df["Full Name"].str.replace(df["TextToRemove"],"")` but got a "'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed" Exception Message. Have also tried using `np.where` and `np.select` without much success.

Only other options I can think of is to do a for loop but would love to know if there is a better way. This file contains over 10 000 rows.

```
                                              Full Name         TextToRemove
0                     2015 Hyundai i30 Active Auto MY16     2015 Hyundai i30
1                           2017 Kia Cerato S Auto MY18      2017 Kia Cerato
2                           2017 Kia Cerato S Auto MY17      2017 Kia Cerato
3                       2017 Kia Cerato Sport Auto MY17      2017 Kia Cerato
4                           2019 Kia Cerato S Auto MY19      2019 Kia Cerato
```

Comment: Does `TextToRemove` correspond one-to-one for `Full Name`? In other words, if the first Full Name was `2015 Hyundai i30 2017 Kia Cerato MY16`, will it become `MY16` or `2017 Kia Cerato MY16`?

Comment: The TextToRemove columns do correspond 1-1. Every "Full Name" column has a corresponding "TextToRemove" column.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you accept it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply`:

```
df["full_name"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["full_name"].replace(x["text_to_remove"], ""), axis=1)
# 525 µs ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Or using `numpy` (which is faster):

```py
df["full_name"] = np.char.replace(df["full_name"].values.astype(str), df["text_to_remove"], "")
# 91 µs ± 2.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each) --> ~5.8 times faster
```

This replaces the `full_name` column with the removed text.

```
|    | full_name        | text_to_remove   |
|---:|:-----------------|:-----------------|
|  0 | Active Auto MY16 | 2015 Hyundai i30 |
|  1 | S Auto MY18      | 2017 Kia Cerato  |
|  2 | S Auto MY17      | 2017 Kia Cerato  |
|  3 | Sport Auto MY17  | 2017 Kia Cerato  |
|  4 | S Auto MY19      | 2019 Kia Cerato  |
```